# Segmentation fault when allocating memory for a 2D array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

This program takes arguments from the command line and displays their prime factors using threads.  I am using a struct to pass info between threads.  The struct has a 2D array that holds the arguments and then their factors.  The way i'm allocating now allows me to access two of my arguments and the gives me a Segmentation fault (Location of Segmentation fault is noted in the code).  What am I doing wrong? All code is provided below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Global variables
#define MAX_FACTORS (11)
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

struct Buffer {
    int **factors;
    int size;
};


void *factor ( void *buffer );
void *displayFactors (void *factors);


// MAIN
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Create Buffer
    struct Buffer *buffer;
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct Buffer));
    buffer->size = argc - 1;

    // Allocate memory for factors 2d array
    buffer->factors = malloc(buffer->size);

    for( int i = 0; i < buffer->size; i++) {
        buffer->factors[i] = calloc(MAX_FACTORS, sizeof(int));
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);

    if(buffer->size > 0) {
        for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
            buffer->factors[i - 1][0] = atoi(argv[i]);
            // ---SEGMENTATION FAULT OCCURS HERE AFTER LOOPING TWICE.----
        }
    }
    else
        return 0;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

    pthread_t producer;
    pthread_t consumer;

    pthread_create(&producer, NULL, factor, (void*)buffer);
    pthread_create(&consumer, NULL, displayFactors, (void*)buffer);

    pthread_join(producer, NULL);
    pthread_join(consumer, NULL);

    free(buffer->factors);

    return 0;
}


// PRODUCER
void *factor ( void *buffer ) {
    struct Buffer *prod_buffer = (struct Buffer*)buffer;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);

    // find numbers to factor factors
    int i = 0;
    while(i < prod_buffer->size) {
        // printf("Numbers to factor: %d\n", prod_buffer->factors[i][0]);
        prod_buffer->factors[i][0] = prod_buffer->factors[i][0];
        i++;
    }

    // Factor numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < prod_buffer->size; i++) {
        int j = 1;
        int toFactor = prod_buffer->factors[i][0];
        while(toFactor % 2 == 0) {
            prod_buffer->factors[i][j] = 2;
            toFactor = toFactor / 2;
            j++;
        }
        for(int k = 3; k <= toFactor; k += 2) {
            while (toFactor % k == 0) {
                prod_buffer->factors[i][j] = k;
                toFactor /= k;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    return NULL;
}


// CONSUMER
void *displayFactors (void *buffer) {
    struct Buffer *cons_buffer = (struct Buffer*)buffer;

    for (int i = 0; i < cons_buffer->size; i++) {
        printf("%d: ", cons_buffer->factors[i][0]);
        for (int j = 1; j < MAX_FACTORS; j++){
            if(cons_buffer->factors[i][j] != 0) printf("%d ", cons_buffer->factors[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return NULL;

}
```

EDIT--
The arguments i've been testing with are 4, 13, 46, 72, 5, and 12.  The result should display: 
4: 2 2 
13: 13 
46: 2 23 
72: 2 2 2 3 3 
5: 5 
12: 2 2 3

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you used a debugger to help you find the problem? At a minimum it will tell you exactly which line of code is triggering the seg fault. And then you can investigate further at that point by inspecting the state of relevant variables.

Comment: `while(toFactor % 2 == 0)`. That looks like it could be an infinete loop. Because `toFactor = toFactor / 2;` is integer division and results in a `toFactor` value which is always an exact multiple of 2. So `(toFactor % 2 == 0)` will always be true.

Comment: Well for one, `displayFactors()` isn't locking the mutex to access the buffer, so it may be trying to display values while you're still factoring.  Also, `main()` *does* lock it at a time when there are no other threads to lock out yet, which is unnecessary.  And if `displayFactors()` *did* lock the mutex, your two threads would basically run sequentially since one would lock out the other until it's more or less done its work... and you'd have a potential race condition (what if the consumer thread starts displaying data before the consumer locks the mutex?)

Comment: @keylum Ive added a comment to the code to show where the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: `buffer->factors = malloc(buffer->size);` --> `buffer->factors = malloc(buffer->size * sizeof(int *));`

Comment: @kaylum  Multiplying the size by the sizeof ( int* ) did the trick.  Thank you.

Comment: @Dmitri Do i need a counter in my buffer struct to keep things in line?

Comment: You could add a counter that counts how many numbers have been factored, and a condition variable.  Lock the mutex only when accessing the counter.  The consumer would wait on the condition whenever the counter is not greater than the number of numbers it's displayed already, and the producer would increment the counter and signal the condition whenever it finishes factoring a number.  Then both threads can run concurrently but will never access the same part of the array at the same time.

Comment: Also, `while(toFactor && (toFactor % 2 == 0)) {` and `while (toFactor && (toFactor % k == 0)) {` to avoid infinite loops if `toFactor` is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use gdb to debug your code, I found that the size of `buffer->factors` is 8, that is not enough.

you should do

```
buffer->factors = malloc(buffer->size*sizeof(int *));
```

This `segmentation fault` error can fix.

Also,There is another bug in your code. if the `consumer` execute first, the output will empty, so you need use the `cond` to make the `producer` exectue first.

Here some tips:

```
pthread_cond_t product = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; /*global*/ 
pthread_cond_signal(&product);  /*In factor function*/
```

**Also the `displayFactors` need to add a mutex**.

```
/*in displayFactors function*/
pthread_cond_wait(&product, &mutex1);
```

And where to put those statements, you should figure it out by yourself. 
Hope that can help you.

Comment: That was it, Thank you!

Comment: That should be `sizeof(int *)` not just `(int *)`. Or `sizeof(*buffer->factors)`.

Comment: @immibis You are right, I am so shame of that error. Thank you for pointing that.